# Is tracking the amplitude of sound on AudioKit enough for start/stopping action on device?

Tags: audiokit

We are tracking the microphone of a device with AudioKit to make action according to the amplitude of the sound.

When the sound reaches a level of amplitude for 3 seconds, it starts an action on the device. As we have seen that frequency may vary a lot even with a constant sound, we focus on the amplitude. The amplitude has a range that is minder vary than frequency.

Is tracking amplitude enough to do the action? Do we have to convert amplitude to dB to have more stable value?

How to extract the lowest amplitude in this range (when sound running)?

I don't know if there is an implemented solution in AudioKit.

Answer (score 0):

Tracking amplitude is a fine way to trigger actions.  Converting to dB is just scaling the values and shouldn't affect anything really.  Just set your threshold and make sure the tracked amplitude doesn't dip below that value for a certain amount of time.  This is baked into the Amplitude Tracker, it can call a call back whenever the threshold value is passed so you can check time stamps between the time the threshold is passed on the way up and down.

Comment: Is there an example how we can assign a callback to  AKAmplitudeTracker? Also timestamps I didnt understand. thx